# Cannot edit visudo

Tags: sudo, users, group, administration

I have to give my user permission to run `sudo`. I am using CentOs

```
# uname -a
Linux lab-hv1-centos1 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and have root access.

A lot of resources recommend to run `visudo` and add line like

```
myuser    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

But attempt to run `visudo` (and even `less /etc/sudousers`) prints message

```
E437: terminal capability "cm" required
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Some articles recommend to install `ncurses-term` using `yum install ncurses-term`. I have done this successfully and indeed number of terminals listed here `ls /usr/share/terminfo/d` is high. However it does not help me: the error message when running `visudo` is still printed and I cannot edit this file.

So, I wanted to add my user to sudo group. But this group did not exist on my machine. I created this group using `groupadd sudo` and then added my user to this group using command `useradd -G sudo myuser`.

This worked successfully but still when I try to run any command with `sudo` I get error message:

```
$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for myuser:
myuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
$
```

The error message indeed correct. `myuser` belongs to group named `sudo` but that was me that created this group. It is just called `sudo`, it does not mean that users that belong to this group have permissions. I believe that if I can add line like

```
myuser    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

or

```
sudo    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to `/etc/sudousers` I am done but I cannot do this due to error described above (`terminal capability "cm" required`)

What's the solution?

Comment: Did you start a new shell after installing the ncurses-term package? If you have root access, you might consider copying the file `/etc/sudoers` to `/root/sudoers.backup` and add the line manually using `echo "myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers`

Comment: Sure, I started new shell several times. I will try to add new line as you recommended. I thought about it by decided to try to solve the problem by the book first.

Comment: @Lambert, this worked for user but not for group `sudo`. Anyway this solves my problem, so if you post your comment as an answer I will be glad to accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you start a new shell after installing the ncurses-term package?

If you have root access, you might consider copying the file `/etc/sudoers` to `/root/sudoers.backup` and add the line manually using:

```
echo "myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

If you want to give access to a group instead of a user you will need to prefix the groupname with the percent character:

```
echo "%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Keep in mind that the last matching rule will be effective in the sudoers file so editing the sudoers file using an editor is still advised to be the recommended way.

EDIT:

Another point of thought, what is the value of your `$TERM` variable? Try to set it using `TERM=vt100` before issuing `visudo` or use one of the following:

```
TERM=vt100 visudo
TERM=xterm visudo
TERM=dumb visudo
```